# Skip Column in OPENROWSET (BULK)

Tags: sql-server

Trying to bulk insert lots of rows into a table.

My SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO [NCAATreasureHunt-dev].dbo.CatalinaCodes(Code)
SELECT (Code)
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NCAATreasureHunt\10RDM.TXT',
       FORMATFILE='C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NCAATreasureHunt\formatfile.xml') as t1;
```

10RDM.TXT:

```
DJKF61TGN7
Q9TVM16Z6Z
X44T4169FN
JQ2PT1ZXZK
C7NW71QPNG
SFJRR1FWKZ
TYZJW1ZPFY
9MR3M1J3N5
QJ6R217JTK
TVJVW19TYT
```

formatfile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
        <FIELD ID="C1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n"/>
    </RECORD>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="C1" NAME="Code" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" />
    </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

This is the error I'm getting:
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Claimed', column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I'm trying to skip the Claimed column. What am I doing wrong in my format file?

Answer (score 0):

See if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347254/bcp-import-error-with-xml-format-file-and-identity-column) helps.

> With an XML format file, you cannot skip a column when you are
>   importing directly into a table by using a bcp command or a BULK
>   INSERT statement. However, you can import into all but the last column
>   of a table. If you have to skip any but the last column, you must
>   create a view of the target table that contains only the columns
>   contained in the data file. Then, you can bulk import data from that
>   file into the view.
>
> To use an XML format file to skip a table column by using
>   OPENROWSET(BULK...), you have to provide explicit list of columns in
>   the select list and also in the target table, as follows:
>
> INSERT ... SELECT FROM OPENROWSET(BULK...)

Comment: I am using the OPENROWSET(BULK ...) though :(