# Very simple bulk insert inserts NULLs for each row in CSV

Tags: t-sql, bulkinsert

I can hear you saying: Then it ain't so simple, is it.

Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [bulkimport].[Test](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Data] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Test_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Here's the tsql:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE bulkimport.Test

BULK INSERT bulkimport.Test 
FROM 'D:\Referenzliste_VKnr.csv' 
WITH (
    FORMATFILE='D:\VKnrImport.xml', 
    CODEPAGE=28591,
    ERRORFILE='D:\VKnrImportError.txt'
)
```

My Config File looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
        <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" />
    </RECORD>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="1"  NAME="Data" LENGTH="50" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" />
    </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

and finally, an excerpt from the data:

```
18
26
34
42
59
67
75
83
91
109
117
125
133
```

There's a carriage return line feed after each row, leaving one empty line at the end. I get a NULL for each entry in the csv file, using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Try just \r or just \n.  That worked for me once.  Maybe not your problem but it is only a comment.

Comment: unfortunately, no dice :(

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't an exact duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347254/bcp-import-error-with-xml-format-file-and-identity-column) (you didn't get any errors) but it's the same problem. As the documentation [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250.aspx):

> With an XML format file, you cannot skip a column when you are
>   importing directly into a table by using a bcp command or a BULK
>   INSERT statement. However, you can import into all but the last column
>   of a table. If you have to skip any but the last column, you must
>   create a view of the target table that contains only the columns
>   contained in the data file. Then, you can bulk import data from that
>   file into the view.

In other words, you can only skip the *last* column in the table when using an XML format file. But you are trying to skip the `Id` column, which is the *first* column.

Two solutions are:

- Use a non-XML format file
- Use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)

When I used this non-XML format file, your data loaded fine:

```
10.0
1
1       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\r\n"   2     Data         Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

But `OPENROWSET` is more flexible, because you can use the `SELECT` to re-order the columns or otherwise manipulate the data coming from the flat file.

Comment: I tried editing the target table to not include an id column, so I wouldn't be skipping any. Same result as described above.